# How can I validate mask TextBox using a button in Windows application?

Tags: c#, windows, maskedtextbox

How do you validate a `Mask TextBox` using a button I tried this so far but no luck the event triggers when `Mask TextBox` is not `focus` anymore. Also it won't accept current year, it only accepts lower years.

I'm using a touch screen monitor for this so when I tapped my `Mask TextBox` it directs me to another form containing another `Mask TextBox` and `buttons` from `0-9` and an `Submit button` and I want to put the validation on my Submit button.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    maskedTextBox1.Mask = "00/00/0000";
    maskedTextBox1.ValidatingType = typeof(System.DateTime);
    maskedTextBox1.TypeValidationCompleted += new TypeValidationEventHandler(button1_Click);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, TypeValidationEventArgs e)
{
    if (!e.IsValidInput)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("The data you supplied must be a valid date in the format mm/dd/yyyy.");
    }
    else
    {

        DateTime userDate = (DateTime)e.ReturnValue;

        if (userDate >= DateTime.Now)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The date in this field must be less or equal than today's date.");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends, what exactly do you plan on doing to the data that is passed into the textbox?

Comment: @NFaneDev its suppose to be inputting the user's `birth date` then after `button click` program will validate if date is acceptable or not.

Comment: I was more so concerned about what happens to the data itself? Do you save the data to a database or is it used for short term verification?

Comment: @NFaneDev Yes, I save it on a database. But how's is it related to my problem?

Comment: Okay well in that case I assume you basically want to make sure that the data that is passed in will be valid in a Date field in your database? In that case you can simply implement the validation manually by converting what the user entered to the format that your db uses, and validating it to make sure it will be acceptable to save in the db.

Comment: I think better to think what you are going to do.The validation sequence begins when one of the following occurs:
 - MaskedTextBox control looses focus.
 - The Text property is retrieved.
 - The ValidateText method is called.

Comment: @Seminda Yeah that was my plan first but I'm using a touch screen monitor for this so when I tapped my `Mask TextBox` it directs me to another `form` containing another `Mask TextBox` and `buttons` from `0-9` and an `Submit` button and I want to put the validation on my `Submit button`.

Comment: Nothing special is needed.  You just got completely lost when you turned the Click event handler for the Submit button into an event handler for the TypeValidationCompleted event.  You of course need *two* event handlers.  One for the validation event, another for the click event.

Comment: @HansPassant How do I do it?

Comment: @HansPassant Mine trigger every input, for example on `month` I input `13`, the event triggers even I haven't complete the `MM/DD/YYYY` format